# why my write statement is not working for a txt fie

Tags: python-3.x

```
f=open("panja.txt","rt")
print(f.read())
f.write("thank you")
```

Running this gives me the following error:

> io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable`

Writing the file will include that string to my file, but it shows not writable though i used `"r+"`

Comment: In your code it seems you used `rt` not `r+`.`rt` is "read text".

Answer (score 2):

You aren't opening it with the `'r+'` flag. You opened it with the `'rt'` flag which is the 'read text' flag. This is a pure read flag, which doesn't have write privileges.

It will work when swapped to `'r+'`.